# Examples of proofs by making reduction to a finite set

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, lo.logic, big-list

This is a very abstract question, I hope this is appropriate.
Suppose $T$ is some claim over some infinite set $A$, for example, let $A$ be the set of all loopless planar graphs, and $T$ be the claim "for every element $a \in A$, the chromatic number of $a$'s dual graph is $\leq 4$" (this is known as "Four-color Theorem"); or, let $A = \mathbb{N}$, and $T$ be the claim "there are no 3 elements $x, y, z \in A$ such that $x^5 + y^5 =z^5$" (a specific case of Fermat's last theorem).
In the first example, it is possible to prove the claim $T$ by testing some claim $T'$ over **finite** set $A' \subset A$, see [proof by computer section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#Proof_by_computer). This is done by a series of reductions, showing that if all the elements in some finite set satisfy a property, then the (original) claim holds.
In some sense, mathematical induction is similar: we test a claim on finite set ("the base case"), then proving $a_n \rightarrow a_{n+1}$, which shows the claim is correct for all space.

Are there more known cases like that? i.e. proving (a combinatorial) claim by reduction to finite cases?

Comment: I think that this is a very interesting question, but I think it doesn't fit the MO mission of focussed questions with a definite answer.  MO has some tolerance for [big-list questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/big-list), so maybe it would be appropriate if made community wiki.  (You can do this by flagging your own post for moderator attention, if you agree.)

Comment: There are certainly a lot of proofs which are vaguely similar to the Four Colour Theorem; search for 'discharging method' which is a (the most common but certainly not the only) way to reduce a general graph problem to a finite set of cases to check.

For a rather different example, in some sense Helfgott's proof of the weak Goldbach conjecture is of this form: he reduces the problem to checking finitely many cases and then does the check. I think this is an example of what you don't want to see (because without the finite check Helfgott still proves something; that's not true for 4CT).

Comment: Since I am no expert I leave this as a comment rather than an answer. The proof of the Poincare conjecture comes to mind which -as described [here](http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/sormani/others/perelman/introperelman.html) (see the section: Transparencies), is based on reduction of different manifolds to a finite set of well-defined ones.

Answer (score 9):

Doron Zeilberger has beat the drum rather enthusiastically for this style of argument; see for example his paper [The C-finite Ansatz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3473).  M. D. Hirschhorn has a paper entitled [A Proof in the Spirit of Zeilberger of an Amazing Identity of Ramanujan](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690530) in which he says,

> In this paper I show that in order to prove Ramanujan's statement it is
>    sufficient to check just the first seven cases, and then I do so.

More controversially, Zeilberger goes further and champions the notion of a "semi-rigorous proof," saying that even if we don't have a fully rigorous proof that the finitely many cases we have checked imply the general case, often the finitely many cases are "good enough."  However, even if you don't agree with Zeilberger's attitude toward semi-rigorous proofs, he and his collaborators have many examples of fully rigorous proofs of the type you are looking for.

Comment: In some sense, Zeilberger either always proves statements by reduction to finite sets (depending on your interpretation) because he is an ultrafinitist and, in particular, _he firmly rejects the very notion of infinity_.

For instance, see [this opinion piece](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/Opinion108.html).

Comment: @ferrari, I don't mean to pick on a typo, but I wonder if I'm missing something.  Is the word 'either' really intended in the sentence "… Zeilberger either always proves statements by reduction to finite sets …"?

Comment: @LSpice, you're right; I was going to write that he either always does or never does depending on your interpretation. He rejects the notion of infinity, so your initial set of interest would be finite anyways from his point of view...

Answer (score 6):

The [15 and 290 theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_and_290_theorems) are of this form.  For example, the 15 theorem says that if a positive definite quadratic form with integer matrix represents all positive integers up to 15, then it represents all positive integers.

Answer (score 5):

It is very common, when finding solutions to Diophantine equations, to use Baker's method of linear forms in logarithms to reduce the problem to a finite computation (that is, to find an upper bound for the solutions).

Answer (score 5):

In 1972, I have developed a general theory of isometric embeddings of finite metric spaces into finite-dimensional Banach spaces, in particular, the injective case, i.e. into metrically injective spaces $\mathbb R^n$ with metrics given by $\max$. An announcement has appeared a couple of years later in AMS Notices. One of the theorems fits the present thread:

For every natural $k\ n$, there is an EXPLICIT natural constant $\mu(k\ n)$ such that the following two statements are equivalent:

> (i) every $k$-element metric space can be isometrically embedded
>          into $\mathbb R^n$ with the distance given by $\max$;
>
> (ii) every $k$-element metric space with integer distances and of diameter
>      ${\leq} \mu(k\ n)$ can be isometrically embedded into subspace
>      $\{0\ \ldots\ \mu(k, n)\}^n$ of $\mathbb R^n$ with the distance
>      given by $\max$.

For each natural $\ n,\ $ there exists a maximal $\ u(n)=k\ $ as above;
and also $\ U(n)\ $ similar to $\ u(n)\ $ but for ALL $n$-dimensional Banach spaces TOGETHER (for each fixed dimension $\ n).\ $ Then in the non-trivial case of $\ n \geq 2\ $ we get

$$ n+2 \leq u(n) \leq U(n) \leq \left\lceil\frac{3\cdot n}2\right\rceil + 1 $$

We see from (i)+(ii) that finding $u(n)$ has been reduced to a finite computation.

Comment: I notice all the extra spaces around the mathematical symbols, and I find them distracting.

Comment: Actually the lower bound $n+2$ may be replaced by $n+C$ for any constant $C$ and large enough $n$, see our paper with Stolyarov abd Zatitskiy in Mathematika 56 (1), 135-139, (2010)

Comment: @FedorPetrov, thank you! Indeed, one thing is to expect 2-->C, another is to prove it. What was your estimate of C=C(n)? (I am asking because I don't have any access to materials outside the Internet, and even this is not so smooth).

Comment: @MattF., there are trade-offs. Overall, I feel that the advantage of extra space is significant (sure, people get used to somethings hence they react against changes). However, occasionally, one could use TeX "\," instead of "\ ".

Comment: @WlodAA it relies on Ramsey numbers for hypergraphs, so we are not proud of the bound at all, and did not even write it explicitly. Some iterated logarithm.

Comment: Here is a pdf https://drive.google.com/file/d/135Q9Ems_qfAMsk-ueE1mFMDnxRUec127/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: For people who want to insert space before math formulæ, it is easy to insert it (by a CSS rule that looks for the `math-container` class) universally on a reader-by-reader basis.  However, for people like @MattF. and me who are disturbed by it, I think that it is not so easy to remove it universally on a reader-by-reader basis, and it is definitely *much* harder, if not impossible, to remove it conditionally (since most MOers do not insert it).

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, let me mention the direction which is opposite to the OP's Question.

There are combinatorial optimizations problems which deal with a finite (but large) input set at the start, and the point is to optimize a real function over the input. Such problems are often messy.

Then, some time ago, Hungarian mathematicians started to embed the input set into a Euclidean n-space, and they'd extend the said function to a linear or convex function over the convex hull of the input. Since the optimum over the whole hull is reached at a vertex then... etc.

We see that sometimes situations which are strictly finite (looking for an ***exact*** answer) get hm-reduced to infinite situations.

Answer (score 2):

[Hales' proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture#Hales'_proof) of the Kepler conjecture:

> "... he embarked on a research program to systematically apply linear programming methods to find a lower bound on the value of this function for each one of a set of over 5,000 different configurations of spheres. If a lower bound (for the function value) could be found for every one of these configurations that was greater than the value of the function for the cubic close packing arrangement, then the Kepler conjecture would be proved. To find lower bounds for all cases involved solving about 100,000 linear programming problems." [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture#Hales'_proof)]

Comment: But see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/317692) for a discussion of whether it's reasonable to think of the proof as reducing the theorem to a finite computation, which is then carried out.

Answer (score 1):

For a somewhat different class of examples, there are some problems in differential topology that can be solved with [bordism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism):

1. First, show that the quantity you want to compute is a bordism invariant, i.e. a group homomorphism from the appropriate bordism group to an abelian group.
2. Then, determine a finite list of generators of the bordism group. (This step is typically the most difficult.)
3. Check on the generators.

Thus a problem that *a priori* is about an incredibly large number of manifolds and must be checked in generality is reduced to a finite set of cases.

Here are some examples.

- In dimension 4, the [Hirzebruch signature theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch_signature_theorem) states that if $M$ is a closed, oriented 4-manifold, the first Pontrjagin number of $M$ is three times the signature $\sigma(M)$ of its intersection form. One proves this by showing that both $\sigma(M)$ and $p_1(M)$ are oriented bordism invariants, and that the bordism group $\Omega_4^{\mathrm{SO}}\cong\mathbb Z$, generated by the class of $\mathbb{CP}^2$. It then suffices to compute $\sigma(\mathbb{CP}^2)=1$ and $p_1(\mathbb{CP}^2)=3$.
- [Rokhlin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rokhlin%27s_theorem), that the signature of a closed, spin 4-manifold is divisible by 16, can be proven in a similar way: $\Omega_4^{\mathrm{Spin}}\cong\mathbb Z$, and the class of the K3 surface is a generator. Then one computes $\sigma(\mathrm{K3}) = -16$. (However, this isn't the standard proof.)
- An application to mathematical physics: while we don't know rigorously what a quantum field theory is, physical arguments suggest that it should come with data of an *anomaly*, which generally determines a bordism invariant in one dimension higher. Anomaly cancellation involves proving this bordism invariant vanishes, which can be checked on a set of generators. For example, a [recent paper of Freed and Hopkins](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.09916) applies this to M-theory.

Comment: of course, this was also the original approach to the atiyah-singer index theorem, encapsulating hirzebruch and rokhlin...

Comment: @MikeMiller oh -- I didn't realize the heat kernel proof was't the original!